# Scope of rule "String literals should not be duplicated" (squid:S1192)

Tags: sonarqube

> **String literals should not be duplicated (squid:S1192)**
>
> Duplicated string literals make the process of refactoring error-prone, since you must be sure to update all occurrences.

The rule currently allows a few exceptions:

- Duplicate literals in annotations
- Strings with less than 5 characters

There is another situation where I don't think that the rule should apply: **Logging statements**.

I argue that logging statements should not affect business logic and therefore are out of scope for this rule. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've deactivated this rule because it gives more false-positives than anything else - "SELECT " ... "FROM " ... "JOIN " ... "LEFT JOIN " ... in an application with many SQL statements this rule is stupid. It should allow a list of string literals to be ignored

Comment: Looks like the discussion was moved to the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/log$20string$20duplicate/sonarqube/B1iUm_LJz60/4VE21HiWDAAJ)

Comment: Now that the Google Group has been abandoned I created a new post about this in the new community forum: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/fp-squid-s1192-logging-statements/187